# Ambiguos Reference to intValue

Tags: swift, swift3

i have a problem with swift 3 that would not show up with swift 2. I read a json a value, and call the function `intValue` (`integerValue` of swift 2) and xcode do I get error

> "ambiguos reference to intValue".

why?

```
let errorcode = json["errorCode"]

switch(errorcode?.integerValue){
    case 1?
```

Comment: What type does `errorcode` have?

Comment: It is the bad request . error 400. I read the response the number of custom errorcode from the backend developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `json` has the type `[String: AnyObject]`, 
`errorcode` has the type `AnyObject?` and

```
errorcode?.intValue
```

is ambiguous because both `NSNumber` and `NSString` have a `intValue`
property. You can cast the value to the expected `NSNumber` type

```
let errorcode = json["errorCode"] as? NSNumber // type is `NSNumber?`

switch errorcode?.intValue {
case 1?:
    // ...
}
```

or cast it directly to an `Int`:

```
let errorcode = json["errorCode"] as? Int // type is `Int?`

switch errorcode {
case 1?:
    // ...
}
```